# Button :hover effects - MC

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, css, html

I'm failing to get button :hover effects working in Marketing Cloud.

These are custom coded emails, with the correctly applied hover classes and properties.
The emails have been tested with Mailchimp and are working in Gmail when delivered from Mailchimp.
No hover effects are working when sent from the Marketing Cloud.

Preview and test does show that hover is working, but the final delivered email does not correctly apply hover effects when viewed in the inbox.

I know that Mailchimp does use quoted-printable encoding. Whereas our current emails from MC do not use quoted-printable encoding.

Anyone aware of any issues or code stripping on MC side that could be causing this?

**To be very clear** - Using the exact same email code, the Mailchimp delivered email has button hover working, the same email from Marketing Cloud does not have button hover working.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe `:hover` is fully supported.

Some clients will work and others won't, for sure outlook will not, I just tested on my side.

I will happily retract this if someone has an alternate solution.

Answer (score 1):

> **The CSS `Element:hover` property is NOT supported by every device/domain over there!**

Check out the list of supported devices/domains here.
[Email domains supported CTA hover effect](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/selectors/hover/)

Additionally: You can check out this Email content blocks from an HTML email, which has hover effect Enabled CTA buttons, however these don't support on all domains.
[Hybrid HTML Email template](http://sfmc-ninja.tech/Responsive_HTML_Email_template.html)